# Solving Modular Equations With Identities

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$4+2x≡7 \pmod 8$
Find all possible solutions and note any identities.
Identify how you found the solutions.
Explain what identities are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\implies 2x\equiv3\pmod 8=3+8a$ for some integer $a$

So, as $3+8a$ is odd and $2x$ is even for integer $x,$ there is no solution

More generally, using [Linear congruence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem) ([Proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence)) $ax\equiv b\pmod n$ is solvable iff $(a,n)$ divides $b$

Comment: Thank-you, but I'm not exactly sure how that answers my question... I mean, it does indirectly... Directly, it leaves me wondering. Would you mind explaining it in regards to my question please?

Comment: @Shayna, Please have a look into http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372515/solve-for-x-4x-6-mod-5

Comment: Ah, thank-you very much! It is a lot clearer now. I sat trying to solve that problem for quite some time. I didn't think my professor would be evil enough to give a problem with no solution!